# URL rewriting. Remove question mark and URL parameter

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In my Wordpress project I'm trying to replace question mark and rewrite the URL, removing the 'location' parameter.

Original URL:
`http://localhost/mydirectory/restaurants/japanese/?location=london`
`http://localhost/mydirectory/restaurants/chinese/?location=liverpool`
`http://localhost/mydirectory/restaurants/[...]`

Result:
`http://localhost/mydirectory/restaurants/japanese/london`
`http://localhost/mydirectory/restaurants/chinese/liverpool`

My code doesn't work, I get `http://localhost/mydirectory/location/london/`
instead of `http://localhost/mydirectory/restaurants/japanese/london/`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mydirectory/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^location=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) ^/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Then I've moved the website on a testing server and changed the code:

Original URLs (with the course name and location may vary):
`https://example.com/de/restaurants/japanese/?location=Berlin`
`https://example.com/de/restaurants/chinese/?location=Frankfurt`
`https://example.com/de/restaurants/[...]`

Result:
`https://example.com/de/restaurants/japanese/Berlin`
`https://example.com/de/restaurants/chinese/Frankfurt`

My code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /de/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} location=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Rewritten URL is:
`https://example.com/restaurants/japanese/Berlin`

but I need:
`https://example.com/de/restaurants/japanese/Berlin`

the 'de' is missing.

Comment: I've not seen `^` used in a non-regex. The replacement bit doesn't use regexs. Perhaps you want `$1/%1` because `$1` I think is `/mydirectory/restaurants/japanese/` and `%1` would be `london`.

Comment: You have `RewriteBase /de/` so you skip that part. Add it back in rewrite if required, `/de/$1/%1?`

Comment: Thank you very much. I’ve already tried to do this.  
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /de/$1/%1? [R=301,L`  
But I get:  
`https://example.com/de/locations/Berlin`  
That is the URL of the CPT `Berlin`

Comment: What does CPT mean?

Comment: Can you edit the post please to provide what you are loading, what code you have, and what the result is? Unclear with current details and comments as URLs differ

Comment: I have a custom post type "locations". One of the cpt pages is "Berlin", with this URL `https://example.com/de/locations/Berlin`. So I think that there is a conflict.
And, when I test this URL  `https://example.com/de/restaurants/japanese/?location=test` redirection works well: 'https://example.com/de/restaurants/japanese/test', but I get a 404...

Comment: Please edit the question with the data https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76492458/edit. Not clear what you mean about a conflict but maybe when the issue is posted it'll be visible.